# Passing Array (not Object) for Auth in Laravel

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I've some problem with passing array, please give me some advice so I can solve this matter.

Here is My Controller:

```
$keluhan_list=DB::table('keluhans')
->select(DB::raw('id,produk,username,masalah,id_departemen'))
->where('status','=','Proses')->get();
return view('layanankonsumen.lihattindaklanjut',compact('keluhan_list');
```

And this is part of my Blade view:

```
@if (Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->level == 'MR' || Auth::user()->level == 'PDD' || Auth::user()->id_departemen ==' @foreach ($keluhan_list as $keluhan) {{$keluhan->id_departemen}} @endforeach' ))
```

It's not error but it's not pass the auth. When I try to replace with `Auth::user()->id_departemen == '10'` it's working.

Comment: so `lavel` is column in the users table right ?

Comment: @imrealashu level,id_departemen, was column on my user table, and i want to give permission for user with spesific user id_department to access more.. i try replace it with '10' and its work and i realize that my fault is start when i calling array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One mistake in return view line

```
$keluhan_list=DB::table('keluhans')
->select(DB::raw('id,produk,username,masalah,id_departemen'))
->where('status','=','Proses')->get();
return view('layanankonsumen.lihattindaklanjut',compact('keluhan_list'));// add one more braces before semicolon
```

First add this line in your blade

```
@foreach ($keluhan_list as $keluhan) 
   <?php $id_dept[] = $keluhan->id_departemen; ?>
@endforeach
```

then

```
@if (Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->level == 'MR' || Auth::user()->level == 'PDD' || in_array(Auth::user()->id_departemen,$id_dept) ))
```

Comment: i'm saved :) thank you so much brother, thank you for all reply God may blessyou all

Answer (score 2):

Use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

> Checks if a value exists in an array

```
@if (.... || in_array(Auth::user()->id_departemen, array_column($keluhan_list, 'id_departemen'))
```

Comment: hello @Alexey Mezenin thank you for some advice but it's end with an error like this Call to a member function pluck() on array what should i do ?

Comment: @ChristianusAndre if it's an array, use `array_column($keluhan_list, 'id_departemen')` instead of `$keluhan_list->pluck('id_departemen')`

Comment: hello @Alexey Mezenin the error is gone but still not showing the button i want to show if auth pass coreectly... my id_department is int, i pass it and check with dd($keluhan_list) and its show the value 10 (int) it must be work but it is not T_T

Comment: @ChristianusAndre that's not related to the question you've asked. Just debug all 4 conditions and you'll see which one returns `false`